# How to create a ListField model in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

Basically, what I want to do is have a class of a model which can have any number of images under one variable name. For example, something like this:

```
class ListField(models.Model):
    image_list = a list of images
```

Is there a way to achieve this in Django? If the question is too vague, I can explain in detail exactly what I am trying to do, in order to give you guys a better idea. Thanks!

Alright, here are the details: I have a model for Comic in my website. The Comic model as expected has a field which is the image of the comic. These images are usually quite big and don't really work well with mobile phones. And I am using bootstrap to make my site responsive. So I was thinking that if I divide each of the comic images into individual rectangular panels, and upload and store them under one variable name, I could simply use Bootstrap's grid system to display them responsively.

Therefore, I basically want a way to store several images under one variable name and call them all using a loop. Any ideas?

Comment: Well please do explain more :)

Comment: @aumo- haha ok yes, gonna have to write a lot of things down.

Comment: What would be useful to know is what exactly you mean by image

Comment: @aumo - done, hopefully, it should me more clear now.

Comment: what about  `images foreign key with Comic` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A ListField is a bad move in terms of storing lots of images, particularly as it implies you'd be storing the data as blobs/long strings.

Have a model for each image you want to store, use a proper models.ImageField to get validation, etc, and use a models.ForeignKey to associate them with the relevant Comic

eg

```
class Comic(models.Model):

     title = models.CharField(....)
     ... etc etc


class ComicImage(models.Model):

     comic = models.ForeignKey(Comic, related_name="comic_images")
     image = models.ImageField(upload_to="see/the/django/docs")
     order = models.IntegerField(default=0)  # increment this for each image in a set

     class Meta:
         ordering = ('order', )  # automatically order the images
```

Comment: Hmm makes sense, I will try it out. I was thinking of the list because it would just make my work easier in admin, but you maybe right.

Comment: In the admin you can [use an Inline](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.TabularInline) to manage `ComicImages` on the `Comic` admin page